# rails console returns hashes on class definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, console

just wanted to test some associations in the rails console. Defined classes for that purpose to "contain" the associations.

I recently switched db-adapter from sqlite3 to mysql. Could it be an effect thereof?

Or is it a matter of settings and I can change the behaviour of the rails console in this respect (and possibly others)

Thanks

On the reasonable request by Dan for an example

```
2.6.0 :005 > class Node < ApplicationRecord
2.6.0 :006?>   belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
2.6.0 :007?>   has_many :children, as: :parent
2.6.0 :008?>   end
 => {"parent"=>#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::BelongsToReflection:0x0000560b72e96ed8 @name=:parent, @scope=nil, @options={:polymorphic=>true}, @active_record=Note (**call 'Node.connection' to establish a connection**), @klass=nil, @plural_name="parents", @type=nil, @foreign_type="parent_type", @constructable=false, @association_scope_cache=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000560b72e96a78 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>, "children"=>#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::HasManyReflection:0x0000560b72ebac98 @name=:children, @scope=nil, @options={:as=>:parent}, @active_record=Note (call 'Node.connection' to establish a connection), @klass=nil, @plural_name="children", @type="parent_type", @foreign_type=nil, @constructable=true, @association_scope_cache=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000560b72eba8d8 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>}
```

Comment: If you post your models in question as well as what the console is saying we can definitely give you some good answers. Also, I don't think changing the DB engine has that kind of effect on console output.

Answer (score 0):

It's because how `some_object` is displayed in Ruby console is governed by `some_object.inspect` result. And the 'default' for this is [`Object#inspect`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/inspect) method, which returns this `#` sign followed by object's class name, encoded object id and the list of instance variables.